# How to assign numbers to months of the year? python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to assign

```
1->March
2->April
3->May
11->January
12->February
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: The question might sound very generic, but usually you don't reinvent the wheel with dates and use the appropriate library functions for it, so: Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> {datetime(year=2015, month=x, day=1).strftime('%B'): 1 + (x - 3) % 12 for x in range(1, 13)}
{'April': 2,
 'August': 6,
 'December': 10,
 'February': 12,
 'January': 11,
 'July': 5,
 'June': 4,
 'March': 1,
 'May': 3,
 'November': 9,
 'October': 8,
 'September': 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import calendar
{1 + (i - 3) % 12:calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1, 13)}
```

It's output is

```
{1: 'March',
 2: 'April',
 3: 'May',
 4: 'June',
 5: 'July',
 6: 'August',
 7: 'September',
 8: 'October',
 9: 'November',
 10: 'December',
 11: 'January',
 12: 'February'}
```